# c# files downloaded with httpwebrequest and cookies get corrupted

Tags: c#, download, httpwebrequest, credentials, data-corruption

I am trying to make a program which is able to download files with URI(URL) using httpwebrequest and cookies(for credential information to keep login status).

I can download files with following code but files get corrupted after being downloaded.

when I download xlsx file(on the web page) into text file at local drive, I see some part of numbers and words from an original file in a corrupted file, therefore I assume I have reached to the right file.

however, when I download xlsx file(on the web page) in xlsx file at local drive, it seems like it fails to open saying

> excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Is there any way I can keep fully original file content after I download?

I attach a part of result content as well.

```
private void btsDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string filepath1 = @"PathAndNameofFile.txt";                     
    string sTmpCookieString = GetGlobalCookies(webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri);            
    HttpWebRequest fstRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sLinkDwPage);
    fstRequest.Method = "GET";                                                          
    fstRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();                      
    fstRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(webBrowser1.Document.Url, sTmpCookieString);
    HttpWebResponse fstResponse = (HttpWebResponse)fstRequest.GetResponse();            
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fstResponse.GetResponseStream());                
    string sPageData = sr.ReadToEnd();                                                  
    sr.Close();                                                                         

    string sViewState = ExtractInputHidden(sPageData, "__VIEWSTATE");                   
    string sEventValidation = this.ExtractInputHidden(sPageData, "__EVENTVALIDATION");  

    string sUrl = ssItemLinkDwPage;                                                  
    HttpWebRequest hwrRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
    hwrRequest.Method = "POST";                                                         

    string sPostData = "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=" + sViewState + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + sEventValidation + "&Name=test" + "&Button1=Button";


    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] bByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(sPostData);
    hwrRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    Uri convertedURI = new Uri(ssDwPage);
    hwrRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    hwrRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(convertedURI, sTmpCookieString);

    hwrRequest.ContentLength = bByteArray.Length;
    Stream sDataStream = hwrRequest.GetRequestStream();
    sDataStream.Write(bByteArray, 0, bByteArray.Length);
    sDataStream.Close();
    using (WebResponse response = hwrRequest.GetResponse())
    {
      using (sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sDataStream);
        {
          string sResponseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
          FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

          Byte[] info = encoding.GetBytes(sResponseFromServer);

          fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
          fs.Close();

          reader.Close();
          sDataStream.Close();
          response.Close();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Error");
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*StreamReader* is for dealing with **text** data. Using it corrupts your *binary data(excel file)*.

Write *sDataStream* directly to file. For ex.

```
sDataStream.CopyTo(fs)
```

PS: I prepared a test case (*using similar logic*) to show how your code doesn't work

```
var binaryData = new byte[] { 128,255 };
var sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(binaryData));
var str3 = sr.ReadToEnd();
var newData = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(str3); //<-- 63,63
```

Just compare *binaryData* with *newData*