# Corrupted Excel file after downloading with C# DownloadFile()

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am making a SSIS package that is downloading files from a website. In order to get the right links, I have store a "Full result Set" (Object Variable), which is then using the "For each loop container" to run through the code (as a String variable).

Example url: https://website/data/date1.aspx. If I open this link, it is automatically downloading the excel file date1.xlsx.

Till now I have made the following C# code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        
        string testfile = Dts.Variables["User::filename2"].Value.ToString();
       

        string[] arr = new string[] {testfile};
       
        try
        {
            string myURI = "https://website/data/";
            string myWebString = null, myLocalPath = null;
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            foreach (string fileName in arr)
            {
                myWebString = myURI + fileName;
                myLocalPath = "c:\\sql\\" + fileName+".xlsx";
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(myWebString, myLocalPath);
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(18, "The process failed", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
```

The variables I am using are "date1.aspx", "date2.aspx" etc...
The files now automatically downloaded and stored as "date1.aspx.xlsx" and "date2.aspx.xlsx".

However when I open the excel files I see that the files are corrupted.
But when I import it with Data>From File Excel, excel is able to open the files correctly.

I think there I something wrong with my code. I have no background in C# so I am really doing trial and error method for some days now. Eventually I want to work with the files in the SSIS package, so It would be great to store them in CSV file format directly, because also the "sheet names" in excel will change every time, so it is hard for me to make a "for each loop", because then I need additional code again.

Would be great if somebody is able to help me! Thank you!

The excel file look in notepad like this:

```
‡    ,  —  ±  3  M  ¿  Ù  F
  `  Ó
  í  *  D  ¾  Ø  +  E     ©  Ã    A  [
  £  ½
    %  š  ´    *  }  —  â  ü  H  b
  î    l  †  
  $  ¡  »    9  ª  Ä  6  P  º  Ô  L  f  ä  þ  h  ‚  â  ü  T  n  è    s    â  ü  r  Œ  ü    ‰  £  +  E    ©    &  ”  ®     0  —   ±  F!  `  ê!    h"  ‚  þ"    w#  ‘  þ#    j$  „  ï$      ‚%  œ  &     ®&  ¤   M'  C  â'  Ø  ^(  T  )  ý  q)  g  ê)  à  f*  \  ý*  ó  +  w  ,  ø  b,  X  é,  ß  d-  Z  Ã-  ¹  H.  >  ß.  Õ  ^/  T     0  ý    Š0  €
  1  ü
  Œ1  ‚  2    º2  °  33  )
  ±3  §
  14  '  ¬4  ¢  &5    ˜5  Ž  6  
  –6  Œ  47  *  ¢7  ˜  8    †8  |  9  
  ¸9  ®  :    ®:  ¤  (;    Ž;  „   <  ö  ’<  ˆ  ù<  ï  n=  d  Ë=  Á  Q>  G  µ>  «  8?  .  ¸?  ®  %@     @  –  3A  )  µA  «  ,B  "  ¯B  ¥  C    oC  e  àC  Ö  _D  U  þD  ô  ’E  ˆ  F  ù  F  a   %G  ÷   ‚G  T  ïG  Á  MH    ÍH  Ÿ  RI  $  ÚI  ¬  eJ  7  K  ×  ‘K  c  %L  ÷  ÙL  «  VM  (  íM  ¿  |N  N  ÿN  Ñ  rO  D   P  ×    „P  V
  ëP  ½
  oQ  A  ïQ  Á  vR  H  S  á  ’S  d
  
T  Ü
  ¡T  s  U  ð  žU  p  V  ë  ‹V  ]  W  á  ŒW  ^  GX    ÒX  ¤  xY  J  Z  Ø  uZ  G  
[  Ü  }[  O  \  ä  –\  h  .]     £]  u  C^    Ô^  ¦  J_    ì_  ¾  }`  O  ì`  ¾  ya  K  b  Ó  b  S  úb  Ì  ƒc  U  óc  Å  vd  H  üd  Î  …e  W     f  Û  Øf  †   Ag  ï   Êg  x  ih    õh  £  wi  %  äi  ’  Zj    Ïj  }  Ak  ï  ¾k  l  l  É  Žl  <  m  ¼  ³m  a  !n  Ï  n  >  o  À  œo  J     ÿo  ­   Žp  <
  q  Å
```

Maybe this post is providing the solution, this has a similar problem. However I do not know how to put it in the code...
[c# files downloaded with httpwebrequest and cookies get corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50706561/c-sharp-files-downloaded-with-httpwebrequest-and-cookies-get-corrupted)

Comment: Please paste an example xlsx file here, so we can see the contents.

Comment: Hi mjwills, the excel file contains sensitive information, apologize.

Comment: Excel with an XLS file extension will be gibberish when you open it in Notepad because it's binary data. Excel with an XLSX file extension will also be gibberish when you open it in Notepad - BUT if you rename the file with a .ZIP extension and then extract contents to a new folder then you know you have a non-corrupt modern Excel document. Once extracted, you could open something likeMyExcelFile\xl\sharedStrings.xml and see stuff but that's not going to help with your actual import.

Comment: @Zayfaya83 an `xlsx` file is a ZIP package containing XML files. You can test whether the file is OK simply by extracting it as if it were a ZIP file. If you can import the data though, it seems this is *not* a real Excel file, no matter what extension you used. You can't make something an `xlsx` file just by adding that extension. The file may be an obsolete `xls` file but even then, Excel would be able to open it

Comment: @Zayfaya83 have you tried opening those URLs in a browser? Can you open the file they return? If not, there's nothing you can do in C# -this isn't a client problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not really - Excel does display an error message when an `xls` file has `xlsx` extension. The error message is *Excel cannot open the file 'Book1.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the extension matches the format of the file*. Otherwise you are right, this is how an `xls` file looks in notepad.

Comment: @GSerg Sometimes it is really helpfull if other persons are looking to the problem from a different point of view. I have changed the file format to xls and the corrupted file message is gone. Thank you very much! Any ideas how to convert the files directly to csv :)?

Comment: An SSIS package can read from xls as from csv.

Comment: HI GSerg, yes I know, but for looping through for me it is easier to use CSV, since the sheet names are changing. I used this tutorial to make a new script to convert the xls files to csv: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLIGiRpl7FI.
One more question: the website i am using also needs a username and password. What would be the best we to implement this in the current script? :)